# XCode and ROS integration

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up XCode to work with ROS. To do so I am following this tutorial

[OSX tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/OSX/Tutorials/Setting%20up%20an%20XCode%20Project)

However, at the very beginning of this manual I am running into a problem.
When I execute this line

```
   roscreate-pkg --xcproj cocoa_tutorial roscpp std_msgs
```

I got this error

```
Usage: roscreate-pkg <package-name> [dependencies...]

roscreate-pkg: error: no such option: --xcproj
```

Any ides how to fix this? Or better how to integrate ROS and Xcode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64600/xcode-and-ros-integration/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2013-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem of integrating XCode and ROS is solved, however when I run the code I get asserts.

roscreate-pkg  is deprecated instead create a project with

```
catkin_create_pkg <package_name> [depend1] [depend2] [depend3]
```

This method works if you already have package that you want to develop in XCode. To integrate XCode and ROS firstly generate Makefile for your package

```
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Unix Makefiles"
```

then follow this procedure

[Porting Unix to Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html)

finally,

```
In menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme 
select Run tab and specify path to your binary file
```

---

UPDATE

An easier solution would be

```
generate Xcode project directly by `catkin_make -G"Xcode"`

then open Xcode from console by `open /Applications/Xcode.app your_project.xcodeproj`  

finally,   In menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme 
    select Run on the left, then select Info Tab at the top, and choose a binary fine in Executable.
```

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-10**:
I'm starting down the `ROS` + `IDE` road so thanks for this! I'm curious, what made you choose `Xcode` over something like `Eclipse`?